# Background URLSession on watchOS - what is the cycle?

Tags: watchkit, watchos, watchos-4

I have a class with the delegates for a URLSession. I intend to use it with a background configuration. I understand that the handlers are called when a certain event happens, such as `didFinishDownloadingTo`.

However, I do have the `handle` function on my ExtensionDelegate class:

```
func handle( _ handleBackgroundTasks:
        Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) 
        // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background 
        to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
        for task in handleBackgroundTasks {
             switch task {
                     case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
```

I wonder: where should I handle the data I receive after a download? At the `didFinishDownloadingTo` or at that function on my ExtensionDelegate class, on the appropriate case of the switch statement?

Another question on the same cycle: I read everywhere that one must remember to `setTaskCompleted()` after going through the background tasks.  But I read elsewhere that one should not set a task as completed if the scheduled data transfer hasn't finished. How do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good explanation here.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45127934/3715676)

It worked when I had an array with my `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask`. Then, at the end of my `didFinishDownloadingTo`, I get the task on that array that has the same sessionIdentifier as the current `session.configuration.identifier`, and set it as complete.